# To develop teamviewer like application using java

Tags: java, networking

I would like to develop one application just like teamviewer application using java.So i would like to get help from technical guys who can help me in that.

My queries were,

1.We can connect to a remote desktop over LAN using socket. Is there any way to connect remote desktop over Internet (no LAN).
2.Can we connect to a remote desktop over internet using public IP?
3.Unique address for each machine is MAC address/ Ethernet address.Whether we can use this MAC address for remote desktop connection? 
4.Public IP for the machines connected to a single router may be same.If we can use public IP for remote connectivity, how we can identify different machines in that router?

Answer (score 4):

Simple anwser, yes you could do all of that.  It's far more complex problem than can be answered completly on a forum.  I suggest you start reading, you need to know the basics before you can master the advanced topics like this.

[jrDesktop](http://jrdesktop.sourceforge.net/) looks like a cool open source tool that you could start reading about.  It only supports LAN right now, but that could change.

[Proxy Servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) are usually used to connect two computers on different LAN's.

You are correct that [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) addresses are used to uniquely identify client's sitting behind a public IP.

Answer (score -1):

Application Extention Programing language  AEPL - can but java i dont know

simple webcam and control script:

```
//this language is only supported for me because i invented it :D
//Any Information : gkavreli@gmail.com

@Application.Import[Webcam.xae];
@Application.Import[Remote.xae];
@Application.Import[Input.xae];

@Start(){
webcamera = new Device;
Start.Webcamera = new WebCam.Device;
Remote.GetInput(){
Remote.Input(){
BlockUser(){
key = new Input.GetKey(){
Lock;
}
}
}
}
}

@Update(){
Remote.Eneabled = true;
Remote.GetComponent("USERINPUT")
}

@Awake() {
Remote.User(LOCK);
}

//This Is a Simple Script 
//Not Supported by you 
// Email : gkavreli@gmail.com
```